# Setting Leaftlet Map to Container Height in R/Shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny, leaflet

I was wondering if it's possible to set a leaflet output's height to "100%" relative to it's parent container in Shiny/R. I've seen some solutions which set the height relative to an entire body output but for my purpose, my map appears in a small tab panel, as seen [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLtmB.jpg)

I've tried creating a surrounding div with modified CSS and simply changing the output's height variable to 100% with no prevail. I was wondering if anyone has a solution which is responsive to changes of the parent container.

From my understanding, the issue is that the column container created by Shiny doesn't have defined dimension. Below is the related code segements and to look at the issue first hand you can go to [my shiny app](http://beersights.me/shiny/beersights/).

**UI**

```
fluidRow(
         br(),
         tabsetPanel(
           tabPanel("Drink Information",
             column(2,
                    withSpinner(htmlOutput("beerImage"))
             ),
             column(5,align = "center",
                    strong(h4("Name")), 
                    textOutput('beerName'),
                    strong(h4("Primary Category")),
                    textOutput('beerPrimaryCategory'),
                    strong(h4("Secondary Category")),
                    textOutput('beerSecondaryCategory')
             ),column(5, align = "center",
                    strong(h4("Varietal")),
                    textOutput('beervarietal'),
                    strong(h4("Tertiary Category")),
                    textOutput('beerTertiaryCategory'),
                    strong(h4("Style")),
                    textOutput('beerStyle')
             )
           ),
           tabPanel("Drink Location",
            column(9,
                   br(),
                   #This is the output I would like to use 100% of the row
                   withSpinner(leafletOutput("lcboLocations"))
            ),
            column(3,h6("temp"))
           )
         )
     )
```

Comment: I think shiny blocks only have a width dimension (number out of 12 -- 12 meaning 100%). But as it is a web page, I think there are not any height dimension. At least, what you could do is put the width to 100%.

Comment: Hi @F.Privé, yeah the shiny fluid rows do use the 12 column system but currently the width isn't the issue. The map takes up 100% of the it's 9 column container but won't expand to its height.

Comment: In `leafletOutput`, there is a parameter `height`, can't you just use that to increase the height?

Comment: You can set it to an absolute value but setting it to a relative value causes the map to no longer display! When I inspect the element on my browser the map is actually set to 100% of it's parent so I assume there is some issue occurring when Shiny makes the parent container.

Comment: As I said in the first comment, I think a wep page has an unlimited height. So, it's not possible to use 100% of infinity.

Comment: Are you after something like in [this example](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/superzip-example.html) - you can view the code behind this map too.